# Query an entire Array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm building my first NodeJS application and have hit a dead end with a query I'm trying to create.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    email:{
       type: String,
    },
    friends: [{
       name: String,
    }],
    name: {
       type: String,
    }
});
```

My goal is to retrieve every single name from each object in the friends array, and display them to the user.

I have tried:  (And many more)

```
 const friendNames = await User.find( 
    {_id: req.user._id},
    { friends: { name: String } }
)


const friendNames = await User.find( 
    {_id: req.user._id},
    { friends: { $elemMatch: { name: String } }}
)


 const friendNames = await User.find( 
    {_id: req.user._id},
    { friends: { name: {$exists : true} } }
)
```

I thought this would be a pretty simple query, but I either overlooked something or I'm misunderstanding a concept entirely. This is my first major roadblock. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like `const friendNames = await User.find( 
    {_id: req.user._id},
    { friends:1 }
)`

Answer (score 0):

Just a `find({ _id: req.user._id }, { friends: 1 })` should do it. This is using [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#project-fields-to-return-from-query).